# Casting short to boolean entity framework

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a `short` value which represents a `true` or `false` in our system, -1(`true`), 0(`false`).

I was wondering if this kind of casting/conversion is possible inline where model property is being initialized.

```
public bool Foo {get;set;}

example: 

return db.tblSomeTable
 .Where( c => c.FooID == 1)
 .Select( c => new SomeFooModel
 {
    FooID = id,
    Foo = IsTrueOrFalse //value (-1, or 0)
 }
```

I tried using a ternary operator but the syntax doesn't make sense:

`IsFoo = if(IsTrueOrFalse == -1) ? true: false;,` //syntax error it is obvious that `;` is ending statement but the `,` there because there are more properties in this select.

The other way to do this might be to call a function that return true or false based on value passed in but I was wondering if this can be done with minimum lines of code.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: The conditional operator doesn't include an `if`.  it would just be `IsTrueOrFalse == -1 ? true: false`.  But really you can just do `IsTrueOrFalse == -1`.  Note that would set all values that are not -1 to false.

Comment: ahhh darn it, of course. you are right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a boolean expression

```
.Select(c => new SomeFooModel
 {
     Foo = (IsTrueOrFalse == -1)
 }
```

or the conditional operator

```
.Select(c => new SomeFooModel
 {
     Foo = (IsTrueOrFalse == -1) ? true : false
 }
```

Comment: thanks for saving me pulling my hair out, i don't know how i missed that

Answer (score 1):

The ternary statement is written like so:

```
IsFoo = (IsTrueOrFalse == -1) ? true : false
```

i.e. there is no need for the if and because there are other statements you also do not need the semi colon.

**EDIT**

As @juharr said in a comment if the value is anything other than `-1`, `IsFoo` will be set to false. So maybe you should do some extra checks. For example:

```
IsFoo = (IsTrueOrFalse == -1) ? true : (IsTrueOrFalse == 0) ? false : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException() //Or whatever
```

Although that will become unreadable fast.